Postfix doesn't work on clients, due to openssl error
Here is my configuration:
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 3.6
debug_peer_list = mail.domain
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_name = Zikipro
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maillog_file = /var/log/postfix.log
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = domain
myhostname = mail.domain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/nginx/certs/mail.domain/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/nginx/certs/mail.domain/cert.key
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes

It works on server terminal, but If I want to use it in php for example, I got this error:
Could not connect to SMTP host. STARTTLS command failed TLS not available due to local problem

If I try to connect using openssl I have this error:
CONNECTED(00000005)
000C76EE01000000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:tls_validate_record_header:wrong version number:ssl/record/methods/tlsany_meth.c:81:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 323 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

Note: fullchain.pem is made by: trust ca + domain pem + CloudFlare origin pem. I tried also with domain pem + cloudflare origin pem and cloudflare origin pem + domain pem, in all cases I got the same problem

Due to missing details in your question it is unknown if the problem is a server side configuration or wrong access at the client side. "It works on server terminal" - please show what command you've used there and the output you got. "use it in php for example" - please show the relevant code so that one compare it with what worked at the terminal. "If I try to connect using openssl I have this error:" - please show the openssl command you've used. Note that you need to use -starttls smtp if you access a port where explicit TLS (STARTTLS) is enabled.

Openssl command: openssl s_client -connect mail.domain:587 -starttls smtp
Send-email command: echo -e "Subject: Test\n\nThis is a test from server terminal" | sendmail -v myemail@gmail.com
PHP Code: https://hastebin.com/share/ayulemisoh.php

The terminal command (echo ... | sendmail ..) does not test SMTP (and thus also not TLS) at all, is just local delivery. Check your server log for cause of problems with the others - "TLS not available due to local problem" indicates some configuration error, inability to load the certificate files or similar.
